# Why does the font shorthand not work in slotted elements?

Tags: css, custom-element

I'm noticing that font shorthand properties are not working on my elements when the element is slotted inside of a custom element. The same shorthand works fine outside of a custom element and if I split it up into the individual properties, it works fine when applied to a slotted element. I thought maybe this was a quirk in Firefox, but I'm noticing the same thing in Chrome/Edge and Safari. To clarify and re-iterate, this is for a *slotted* element inside a custom element and *not* an element in the custom element's shadow DOM.

Note this does not actually show the issue I'm noticing, which I thought did, but was a localized issue that I'm trying to resolve.

```html
<style>
    h2{
        font: 700 3.125rem/1.12 sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<custom-element>
    <div slot="example-slot">
        <h2>Example H2</h2>
    </div>
</custom-element>
```

I tried looking through MDN and various W3C docs but never found anything touching on this subject directly (not to say they don't exist). I also did general searches on Google and here as well, but mostly got results of folks improperly formatting the shorthand (i.e. forgetting the font-family) or tutorials on how to style the shadow DOM. Maybe I'm using the wrong mix of keywords here, but I would love a pointer in the right direction.

Here's a [series of screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/vbdTInE) indicating what I'm seeing. Another user indicated getting my code in a clean fiddle which has illuminated the fact that my transpiler might be getting in the way. Will reply with further updates once I isolate the problem.

After attempting to replicate the issue using the full minified and transpiled code on a different website, I'm realizing now that the issue is not my transpiler. The problem might be coming from NextJS (though I hesitate to keep pointing fingers) where I'm trying to use these custom elements. I'm able to get around the `document is undefined` issue by dynamically importing the code after the DOM is ready like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    import('local-package/dist/components');
}, []);
```

Seems there's maybe a caveat here that I'm missing. I'll report back if I discover anything to actually solving the problem of not being able to use the font shorthand, but for now, I think the workaround is to just break out the shorthand into "longhand" as that seems to not give me problems and is a cheaper use of my time right now.

Comment: TIL font has shorthand syntax! However, i'm unable to replicate on the newest Edge & FF using a setup almost identical to your example in the OP. It seems to work regardless of how I implement the CSS (inline, as a constructable stylesheet tied to the WC, as a link element... behavior identical with all of them). Could you maybe try and get a working snippet/fiddle going that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: At first I was going to say that it could be a bug but since @diopside can't replicate the error, the only logical conclusion I can see if the component overrides the `font` property and that's why when you get more specific the style is applied. You could try a quick debug adding `!important` see if anything changes

Comment: Please use the [<>] button to convert the code in your post to a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @diopside thanks for the suggestion on the fiddle. I did this locally to make sure I wouldn't be wasting everyone's time, but can't replicate my own issue in a clean fiddle (~~it works on my machine~~). _sigh_. This makes me wonder if the issue lies with my build chain and something is happening in the transpile process. I'll report back once I've got the issue isolated a bit better.

Comment: @savageGoat I added a few images to show what I'm noticing. Unfortunately it didn't work and humorously (imo) made it worse. However, following diopside's advice to put my code into a fiddle illuminated other underlying issues, so there's some more work involved to isolate my problem. Thanks for the suggestion to try something I hadn't thought of yet.